# TPL Dataflow log item if send to ITargetblock

Tags: c#, logging, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm actually facing a problem with TPL dataflow (it seems that an item is added twice). Therefore I wanted to know if there is the option to inject a callback, which I can use for logging, if an item is posted to a target block. I checked the `ActionBlock`, `BufferBlock` constructors, and also the `LinkTo` methods but didn't find anything.

Any hints?

Comment: No, you need to do a decorator block instead, or use some logging buffer, like `TransformBlock` which basically just logs the message

Comment: @VMAtm: Thx for the hint. Please write your comment as the answer, so that I can mark the question as resolved. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as the TPL Dataflow is quite lightweight library, you need to do a decorator block instead, or use some logging buffer, like `TransformBlock` which basically just logs the message, something like this:

```
var loggingTransform = new TransformBlock<TIn, TOut>(m => 
{
    Logger.Info(m);
    return m;
});
```

Some useful links:

- [Guide to Implementing Custom TPLDataflow Blocks](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/1615555D-287C-4159-8491-8E5644C43CBA/Guide%20to%20Implementing%20Custom%20TPL%20Dataflow%20Blocks.pdf)
- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Dataflow Block Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-dataflow-block-type)

Comment: Just a quick question: in the code is the Logger.Info() a static method? This is neat but it seems to introduce a dependency to a specific logger. If I am sure I will use a certain logger then this should work really well.

Comment: @DavidY it's just a placeholder for the real code. C# has closures, and this will be one of them, but only if you need one. Here it's only a demo what to do with the `m` message

Comment: @DavidY You can create your own class, with dependency injection of the logger you need